# Android: programmatically select Gallary image

Tags: android, image-gallery

I have a Gallery view in my application which is working fine. When clicking on a Gallery item, I'm displaying the full image in an ImageView. When the activity is first loaded, I want to display the first image in the full image's ImageView programmatically, so that the user doesn't have to click the first item in the Gallery.

--- Edit ----

```
public void onCreate() {
//other code

    ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.photo_gallary);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gallary__full_img);

    ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            displayFullImg(arg2);               
        }           
    });


ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
ga.setSelection(0);
}//onCreate

private void displayFullImg(int arg2){
  Item item = pics.get(arg2);
  String url = item.getImageUri();
  imageView.setImageBitmap(url);
}
```

Comment: won't gallery.setSelection(0) work?

Comment: Hi Aleadam, I tried this, but not working.

Comment: Why can't you use a similar method as you do in your onClick callback? You can use gallery.getSelectedView() to obtain the View (perhaps, after set it to 0 as above).

Comment: Venkat (or Nehatha?), I'm pretty sure `gallery.setSelection(int)` works, can you post the full code where you are using this? It's probable that the gallery hasn't finished rendering yet.

Comment: Hi @dmon, I have updated my original post. please have a look.

Comment: is displayFullImg(0); not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use directly

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(pics.get(0).getImageUri());
```

Comment: Thanks Aleadam, it's working :)
What if i want to set nth image and want to scroll the Gallary programatically to nth position?

Comment: @Venkat setSelection(n) should scroll to that position. You can use the same method `pics.get(n)` to return the desired URI. Just make sure that you check before whether the URI actually exists.

Comment: @dmon it could be, but if just one line of code does the job, I'll cheat! ;^)

Comment: @Aleadam, setSelection(n) is working fine for the scrolling. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      ga.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
          public void run() {
            ga.setSelection(0);
          }
        }
      });
```