# Combine layout_weight and maxWidth for views

Tags: android, layout, css, landscape-portrait

I'm trying to make my layouts more landscape friendly, and a common pattern I have is to add a `LinearLayout` with some buttons (e.g. OK | Cancel) and just set a value for `layout_weight` so that the space is evenly distributed. The problem is that when you use a phone or (especially) a tablet in landscape mode, you end up with humongous buttons that look ridiculous. I tried setting `maxWidth` on the buttons and on the linear layout but to no avail. What would be the easiest way to achieve this? Namely, setting a maximum horizontal size for the view so that it does not grow to the whole width. I tried a bunch of different things, but none worked.

Here's a sample layout:

```
    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="6dp"
      android:paddingBottom="6dp">
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/button1" />
      <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Note: I know I can create a new layout file for landscape and do magic there. I want to keep the specialized layout files to a minimum, and I would hope this does not require them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Eclipse here to test it, but I would use a RelativeLayout instead, something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
  <View
    android:id="@+id/centerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    />
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/centerView"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/button1" 
    />
  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/centerView"
    android:text="@string/button2" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As I said, I can't test it right now, but you can work around this idea.

On a side note, unless your layout is very simple, I usually create separate layouts for landscape. It's a little more work, but you can optimize the views much better that way. Specially, if you plan to support larger screens.

Comment: BTW, does this qualify as [cheating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254303/android-programatically-select-gallary-image/6255224#6255224)? ;)

Comment: Heh, no this is good. I'm trying it out and worked pretty well, except for the fact that the RelativeLayout ate the EditText that I have above it. But, it looks promising!

Comment: @dmon you'll have to add `android:layout_below="@id/textView1"` (or whatever the id is) to each of the Views. RelativeLayout is a very powerful layout. Take a look at all possible the attrs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html).

Comment: Oy, I finally got it working but these `RelativeLayout`s are a pain. I still prefer how `LinearLayout`s can distribute the empty space so easily.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around quite a bit with relative layouts, I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875877/setting-max-width-of-linearlayout-or-other-viewgroup-on-android), which is what I ended up using.

Comment: I'll assume you meant the "extend LinearLayout and override the onMeasure function" answers on that page. The page has a more recent answer, "Add a Outer Layout" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875877/setting-a-maximum-width-on-a-viewgroup#23072507 which is much simpler (but I didn't test it).

Answer (score -1):

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/rlMain"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

    <View
      android:id="@+id/vCenter"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnOne"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/vCenter"
     <!--Change this for different widths-->
     android:minWidth="200dp"/>

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vCenter"
     <!--Change this for different widths-->
     android:minWidth="200dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add a little explanation to your answer is better for future readers?